# Passing Excel VBA array to parental function?

Tags: vba, excel, parameter-passing

*I don't know if this question will make sense to begin with...*

Example Given: the following value is given for a *single* cell (we'll call it `A1`): `Sub-value #1|Here's another sub-value #2|Yet again, last but not least, sub-value #3`. **I already know someone will tell me that this is where a database should be used (trust me, my major is DB Management, I know, but I need my data in this fashion).** My delimiter is the `|`. Now say I want to create a function that will take the `LEN()` of each sub-value and return the `AVERAGE()` of all the sub-values. If I wanted to create a single function to do this, I could use an `split()`, take each value, do an `LEN()` and return the `AVERAGE()`.

For the example given, let's utilize cell `B1`. I have created similar functions in the past that would work by the following method (although not this exact one), but it requires splitting and joining the array/cell value(s) each time: `=ARRAY_AVERAGE(ARRAY_LEN(A1,"|","|"),"|","|")`.

- `ARRAY_LEN(cell,delimiter[,Optional new_delimiter])`
- `ARRAY_AVERAGE(cell,delimiter[,Optional new_delimiter])`

However, I'm wondering if there might be a more dynamic approach to this. Basically, I want to `split()` an array with some custom VBA function, pass it to parent cell functions, and I wrap up the array by a function that will merge the array back together.

Here's how the cell function will run:
`=ARRAY_AVERAGE(ARRAY_LEN(ARRAY_SPLIT(A1,"|")))`.

- `ARRAY_SPLIT(cell,delimiter)` will split the array.
- `ARRAY_LEN(array)` will return the length of each sub-value of the array.
- `ARRAY_AVERAGE(array)` will return the average of each sub-value of the array. Since this function returns a single value of multiple values, this will take the form of an imaginary `ARRAY_JOIN(array,delimiter)` that would merge the array back again.

This requires one or two additional functions in the cells, but it also lowers the number of iterations that the cell would be converting to and from a single cell value and VBA array.

*What do you think? Possible? Feasible? More or less code efficient?*

Comment: I have to ask: why do you HAVE to have your data this way when you know some type of DB would be a better solution? There's nothing stopping you from putting this into a text or CSV file and then efficiently querying it in Excel with VBA. That file becomes your "database."

Comment: Because most of the work I do is impromptu, one-time-and-I'm-done-with-this-data-structure. The best description for me is that I'm an Information Logistics number cruncher amongst other things (I work both with individual data sets as well as entire summaries). I analyze large sets of data different ways every day. It doesn't make sense for me to throw it into a database when I'm going to need Excel functions to fill, merge, run spreadsheet functions, etc., anyway, and then convert it back to a spreadsheet format in the end.

Comment: I think if you did what I do and a ton of other people who are always thinking of efficient ways to get the job done where I work every day, you'd come to the same conclusion ;-) DB, in theory, is the correct solution. Spreadsheets, in reality, are more efficient for my piece of the process. It's a necessary evil.

Comment: Well you don't need to create actual database tables or anything. It does make sense to download/export your data structures into a format that you can quickly manipulate them with. Getting your structures into a delimited format is fairly simple and querying it with SQL is even easier. You'll end up with two files instead of one since you're end result is an Excel sheet but there's no reason you can't delete the text file after you're done with it. Think about all the time you spend making these custom functions and playing with your data in Excel when you could be using SQL...

Comment: Hm. . .this is true! I'll have to look into that for sure. Unfortunately though, most of the people that I typically work with on these projects have little or no experience with SQL, so I'd probably be the only one (or one of the only ones, even though personally I'd love this option) who would be willing to take this 'extra step,' which is why I always have to consider everyone else and take the less conventional method.

Comment: I'll write you up an example and show you how you can manipulate it in different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 example VBA UDFs that work on a single cell: enter the formula as

=AVERAGE(len_text(SPLIT_TEXT(A1,"|")))

Note that in this particular case you don't actually need the len_text function, you could use Excel's LEN() instead, but then you would have to enter the AVERAGE(..) as an array formula.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Split_Text(theText As Variant, Delimiter As Variant) As Variant
    Dim var As Variant
    var = Split(theText, Delimiter)
    Split_Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(var)
End Function
Public Function Len_Text(something As Variant) As Variant
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim var() As Variant

    If IsObject(something) Then
        something = something.Value2
    End If

    ReDim var(LBound(something) To UBound(something), LBound(something, 2) To UBound(something, 2))
    For j = LBound(something) To UBound(something)
        For k = LBound(something, 2) To UBound(something, 2)
            var(j, k) = Len(something(j, k))
        Next k
    Next j
    Len_Text = var

End Function
```

Comment: Charles, this does answer the original question I had. . .thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Now, this is a very crude example but it should give you an idea of how to get started and how you can customize this method to suit your needs. Assume you have the following data in a text file called **example.txt :**

```
Name|Age|DoB|Data1|Data2|Data3
David|25|1987-04-08|100|200|300
John|42|1960-06-21|400|500|600
Sarah|15|1997-02-01|700|800|900
```

This file resides in the folder **C:\Downloads**. To query this in VBA using ADO you'll need to reference the **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.X Library** where X is the latest version you have installed. I also reference the **Microsoft Scripting Library** to create my **Schema.ini** files at run-time to ensure that my data is read properly. Without the Schema.ini file you run the risk of your data not being read as you expect it to be by the driver. Numbers as text can ocassionally be read as null for no reason and dates often get returned null as well. The Schema.ini file gives the text driver an exact definition of your data and how to handle it. You don't HAVE to define every column explicitly like I have done but at the very least you should set your *Format, ColNameHeader, and DateTimeFormat* values.

Example Schema.ini file used:

```
[example.txt]
Format=Delimited(|)
ColNameHeader=True
DateTimeFormat=yyyy-mm-dd
Col1=Name Char
Col2=Age Integer
Col3=DoB Date
Col4=Data1 Integer
Col5=Data2 Integer
Col6=Data3 Integer
```

You'll notice that the file name is enclosed in brackets on the first line. This is NOT optional and it also allows you to define different schemas for different files. As mentioned earlier I create my Schema.ini file in VBA at run-time with something like the following:

```
Sub CreateSchema()
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream

    Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile(FILE_DIR & "Schema.ini", True)

    ts.WriteLine "[example.txt]"
    ts.WriteLine "Format=Delimited(|)"
    ts.WriteLine "ColNameHeader=True"
    ts.WriteLine "DateTimeFormat=yyyy-mm-dd"
    ts.WriteLine "Col1=Name Char"
    ts.WriteLine "Col2=Age Integer"
    ts.WriteLine "Col3=DoB Date"
    ts.WriteLine "Col4=Data1 Integer"
    ts.WriteLine "Col5=Data2 Integer"
    ts.WriteLine "Col6=Data3 Integer"

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set ts = Nothing
End Sub
```

You'll notice that I use the variable FILE_DIR which is a constant I define at the top of my module. Your Schema.ini file -MUST- reside in the same location as your data file. The connection string for your query also uses this directory so I define the constant to make sure they reference the same place. Here's the top of my module with the FILE_DIR constant along with the connection string and SQL query:

```
Option Explicit

Const FILE_DIR = "C:\Downloads\"
Const TXT_CONN = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" & FILE_DIR & ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;"
Const SQL = "SELECT Name, DoB, ((Data1 + Data2 + Data3)/3) AS [Avg_of_Data]" & _
            "FROM example.txt "
```

Notice the portion in **TXT_CONN** called *Dbq*. This is the directory where your data file(s) are stored. You'll actually define the specific file you use in the WHERE clause of your SQL string. The **SQL** constant contains your query string. In this case we're just selecting Name, DoB, and Averaging the three data values. With all of that out of the way you're ready to actually execute your query:

```
Sub QueryText()
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer

    'Define/open connection
    With cn
        .ConnectionString = TXT_CONN
        .Open

        'Query text file
        With rs
            .Open SQL, cn
            .MoveFirst

            'Loop through/print column names to Immediate Window
            For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
                Debug.Print .Fields(i).Name
            Next i

            'Loop through recordset
            While Not (.EOF Or .BOF)

                'Loop through/print each column value to Immediate Window
                For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
                    Debug.Print .Fields(i)
                Next i

                .MoveNext
            Wend

            .Close 'Close recordset
        End With

        .Close 'Close connection to file
    End With

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

I know that I said doing this is extremely simple in my comments above and that this looks like a lot of work but I assure you it's not. You could use ONLY the QueryText() method and end up with similar results. However, I've included everything else to try and give you some ideas of where you can take this for your project as well as to show you how to solve problems you might run into if you're not getting the results back that you expected.

*This is the guide I originally learned from:* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx

*Here is a guide for doing the same thing to actual Excel files:* http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

*Lastly, here's more info on Schema.ini files:* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx

Hopefully you're able to find a way to make use of all this information in your line of work! A side benefit to learning all of this is that you can use ADO to query actual databases like Access, SQL Server, and Oracle. The code is nearly identical to what is printed here. Just swap out the connection string, sql string, and ignore the whole bit about a Schema.ini file.

Comment: +1 for a thorough, thoughtful answer.  I've never used ADO on text files.  The whole schema part is interesting.

Comment: Kittoes, your question is an awesome alternative, and thank you for your thoroughness.